# How can I create a heatmap using seaborn when one of the columns has an object dtype?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to create a simple heatmap using seaborn.

```
import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns

index = ['0.0001', '0.0001', '0.0001', '0.0001', '0.001', '0.001', '0.001','0.001', '0.01', '0.01', '0.01', '0.01', '0.1', '0.1', '0.1', '0.1']
c1 = ['(16,)', '(16, 16)', '(64, 64)', '(128, 128)', '(16,)','(16, 16)', '(64, 64)', '(128, 128)', '(16,)', '(16, 16)', '(64, 64)', '(128, 128)',  '(16,)', '(16, 16)', '(64, 64)', '(128, 128)']
c2 = [0.5360134 , 0.52964824, 0.53534338, 0.51859296, 0.54304858,
       0.52026801, 0.54036851, 0.51658291, 0.54137353, 0.52361809,
       0.53031826, 0.52931323, 0.53366834, 0.53333333, 0.52663317,
       0.52998325]
d = {'c1':c1, 'c2':c2}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=index)
sns.heatmap(df)
```

But, I'm getting the below value error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(16,)'
```

How can I rectify this?

Comment: You'll need to drop that column.

Comment: @mwaskom Playing around a bit and seems like I just have to convert the dataframe to a pivot table.  No need to drop the column which is essential to this visualization.

Comment: Well, then that is a different question...